# Iterate in a certain base in python

Tags: python, list, radix

I am writing a program that looks for keith numbers in different bases. Is there a way to iterate through numbers in a certain base? I have a program that can convert decimal to any base, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is my code so far.

```
def is_keith_number(n,base):
   # Find sum of digits by first getting an array of all digits then adding them
   c = str(n)
   a = list(map(int, c))
   b = sum(a)

   # Now check if the number is a keith number

   while b < n:
      a = a[1:] + [b]
      b = sum(a)

   return (b == n) & (len(c) > 1)
```

I also have a function,

`convert()`

which converts a number from one base to another. Its unneccesary to show that code, but it does work. Any help?